# What are the differences between running a light node and connecting through the metamask server package?

Tags: go-ethereum, metamask, dapp-development, nodes

What are the differences and what has to be considered to decide which approach to take?

What are the benefits and disadvantages of running a full node, instead of one of those two approaches?

By the way, I'm running a server because it needs to interact with the contract. Instead of running heavy computations in my contract, I look for a solution on the server and send it to the contract, which then simply verifies that the sent solution is in fact one.